# Post like instagram with many photos TabView SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, instagram, tabview

I'm trying to do something like instagram post in SwiftUI.

[image]

I've got array of posts and array of photos in posts.
We using tab view to show photos.

```
                ForEach($viewModel.posts.post, id: \.id) { $post in
                    TabView {
                        ForEach($post.image, id: \.id) { $image in
```

and we got custom tabor indicators:

```
CustomTabBarSegmentControl(tabItemSize: .posts, selectedTab: $selectedTab)
```

The problem are that we need $selectedTab in custom tabBar.  But how I can create personal @Binding/@Published property for every post. If it 1 property in View - it changes all photos in all post at one time. )

Posts:

```
struct Posts: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var post: [Post]
}

struct Post: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var image: [ImagePost]
    let description: String
    
}

struct ImagePost: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let imageString: String
    var isCheck = true
}
```

@Published can't be in struct, @Binding I can't init in every post.

Thanks for help and sorry for long read.

Comment: I'm unclear on the question, but in general, using `ForEach` with indices like this is very dangerous -- make your data `Identifiable` instead and iterate over the items instead of their indices.

Comment: Hi @jnpdx, that's all what I found in the internet how to do it. If you can share link with correct usage ForEach in this case, I'll be grateful.

Comment: `ForEach(posts) { post in ... }`

Comment: Thanks, I've did it.)
but the main problem is still exist )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution:

```
                    ForEach($viewModel.posts.post, id: \.id) { $post in
                    TabView (selection: $post.id) {
                        ForEach($post.image, id: \.id) { $image in
                            ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
                                Image(image.imageString)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: 375.scaled, height: 320.scaled)
                                    .ignoresSafeArea()

                                CheckboxButton(isCheck: image.isCheck) {
                                        image.isCheck.toggle()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: 375.scaled, height: 320.scaled)
                    .tabViewStyle(.page)
                    .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
                    .onAppear {
                        setupAppearance()
                    }
                    
                    CustomTabBarSegmentControl(tabItemSize: .posts, selectedTab: $post.id, foregroundColor: .primary1, backgroundColor: .clear, numberOfTabs: post.image.map{$0.id})
```